# DOCPLEX: tips to manipulate data input (binary parameter)

Tags: python, docplex

I am coding a MIP problem in docplex and I would like to ask for some tips.

I would like to input a binary **parameter** that states a compatibility relation:

I have a set of characteristics $H$ to be satisfied in a product. The product is made by a set of components $C$ and each component can have many variants $V$. For stating the compatibility between variant of component and required characteristics, I stated the following binary parameter:

- $G_h{_{c}}_{v}=1$ if the characteristic $c$ can be accomplished by variant $v$ of component $c$, and zero otherwise

I was wandering to use a 3D numpy array to state this relation. But I if I'm not wrong, I did not find examples using 3D numpy array. Instead, I saw `namedTuple`, that I guess was used to state similar relation for string elements.

How can I code binary parameters in docplex keeping the index of each element, by accessing the value of each parameter and also its key ?

If someone could help me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 5):

One thing I would personally do is stick to dictionaries as accessing each key is easier and faster (Its complexity is $O(1)$). If you have three collections for your keys, namely your $H$, $C$, and $V$, then, as you probably know, you can use [`binary_var_cube`](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html#docplex.mp.model.Model.binary_var_cube) where you can see, from the documentation linked:

> Creates a dictionary of binary decision variables, indexed by triplets.

Using dictionaries will help you tremendously especially in cases where you have a sparse matrix. e.g. only a handful of variants $V$ are present in each component $C$. That way, rather than having a 3D numpy array or list of list of list, you can have only those indices for your variables that exist. Of course, you can achieve that with tuple or `namedTuple`, but as I mentioned, accessing dictionaries is faster (you can read more about some of Python data types [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity))

Comment: thanks for your reply and explanations, I appreciated it!